# No communication between WebService in C# and a software in java

Tags: java, c#, web-services

I have a web service in C#
and a program that sends data in java

here's the web service part:

```
[WebMethod]
public string Client(string request) {
    return "Hello" + request;
}
```

And this is the Java part:

public void send(String url)
    {
        try
        {
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

```
        //add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

        String urlParameters = "request="+this.toJson();

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());    
    }

}
```

I always Result in code 500

If i'm using not a web service just a simple asp.net mvc
the communication works

what i need to change/check in the WebService to establish connection?

UPDATE:
I'm attaching the wsdl:

```html
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<s:element name="Client">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="request" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="ClientResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ClientResult" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="string" nillable="true" type="s:string"/>
</s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="ClientSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Client"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ClientSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ClientResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ClientHttpGetIn">
<wsdl:part name="request" type="s:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ClientHttpGetOut">
<wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ClientHttpPostIn">
<wsdl:part name="request" type="s:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ClientHttpPostOut">
<wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="WeightServerSoap">
<wsdl:operation name="Client">
<wsdl:input message="tns:ClientSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:ClientSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:portType name="WeightServerHttpGet">
<wsdl:operation name="Client">
<wsdl:input message="tns:ClientHttpGetIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:ClientHttpGetOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:portType name="WeightServerHttpPost">
<wsdl:operation name="Client">
<wsdl:input message="tns:ClientHttpPostIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:ClientHttpPostOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="WeightServerSoap" type="tns:WeightServerSoap">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="Client">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Client" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="WeightServerSoap12" type="tns:WeightServerSoap">
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="Client">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Client" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="WeightServerHttpGet" type="tns:WeightServerHttpGet">
<http:binding verb="GET"/>
<wsdl:operation name="Client">
<http:operation location="/Client"/>
<wsdl:input>
<http:urlEncoded/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<mime:mimeXml part="Body"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="WeightServerHttpPost" type="tns:WeightServerHttpPost">
<http:binding verb="POST"/>
<wsdl:operation name="Client">
<http:operation location="/Client"/>
<wsdl:input>
<mime:content type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<mime:mimeXml part="Body"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="WeightServer">
<wsdl:port name="WeightServerSoap" binding="tns:WeightServerSoap">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:55971/WeightServer.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="WeightServerSoap12" binding="tns:WeightServerSoap12">
<soap12:address location="http://localhost:55971/WeightServer.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="WeightServerHttpGet" binding="tns:WeightServerHttpGet">
<http:address location="http://localhost:55971/WeightServer.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="WeightServerHttpPost" binding="tns:WeightServerHttpPost">
<http:address location="http://localhost:55971/WeightServer.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Run the webservice in the debugger and see what the error is.   If you tried that, and it returns 500 without crashing, the problem is probably in your web.config file.

Comment: the web service doesn't receive the request

Comment: check the log. 500 is server error, when you receive the request but fail to interpret it. Enable log in debug mode. The code you provided is not reached - why we need it then? please provide endpoint configuration and where you send the request, most likely you configurred it incorrectly. Note: if you did not reach server, you would recieve 404. 500s are recieved ONLY from server